# Mock patch multiple

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock multiple functions inside a module, from within a TestCase:

```
from mock import patch, DEFAULT, Mock

function_a = Mock()
function_a.return_value = ['a', 'list'] 
with patch.multiple('target.module',
                    function_a=function_a,
                    function_b=DEFAULT) as (f_a, f_b):
```

To my surprise, this is not working, giving me the following Traceback:

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

using: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/

Answer (score 5):

For `patch.multiple`, assigning the patched function name (`function_a`) to any value other than `DEFAULT`, or `unittest.mock.DEFAULT`, will result in the returned dictionary not containing the mocked function.

In other words,
`with patch.multiple('target.module', func_a=SOME_VALUE, func_b=DEFAULT) as mocks:
    mocks['func_a']    # KeyError: 'func_a'`

Also, assigning `with patch.multiple(...) as (f_a, f_b)` is going to give you two strings, which in your case will be `'function_a'` and `'function_b'`. This is equivalent to the operation

```
x = dict(function_a = MagicMock_a, function_b = MagicMock_b)
(f_a, f_b) = x
f_a    # 'function_a'
```

If you wish to access the `MagicMock` object, assign it to the dictionary value instead, something like `mocks['func_a'] = f_a`.

Answer (score 3):

So, from that documentation page you link to:

> If patch.multiple is used as a context manager, the value returned by the context manger is a dictionary where created mocks are keyed by name

But you've got `with patch.multiple(...) as (f_a, f_b)` - *two* values. Looks like it should be `with patch.multiple(...) as fdict`, and `fdict` will be a dictionary with keys `function_a` and `function_b`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Parenthesized Context Managers](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#parenthesized-context-managers) to patch multiple thing with Python 3.10 like so:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch, DEFAULT, Mock

def setup():
    with (
        patch("target.module.function_a", Mock(), return_value = ['a', 'list']) as f_a,
        patch("target.module.function_b", DEFAULT) as f_b,
    ):
        # proceed to test
```